# UnboundLocalError: Decorator with default parameters

Tags: python, decorator

Here is my decorator code. I'm getting UnboundLocalError for some reason but I couldn't find it.

```
>>> def validate(schema=None):
        def wrap(f):
            def _f(*args, **kwargs):
                if not schema:
                schema = f.__name__
            print schema
            return f()
            return _f
        return wrap

>>> @validate()
    def some_function():
        print 'some function'


>>> some_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    some_function()
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 4, in _f
    if not schema:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'schema' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

So, I thought maybe it's better to post here. I might be missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your *full* traceback???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler can't determine `schema`'s proper scope. Either use `nonlocal schema` (3.x) within `_f()` or change the definition of `_f()` slightly:

```
def _f(self, schema=schema, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Hi Ignacio. What do you mean by nonlocal schema?

Comment: I mean the word `nonlocal`, followed by a space, followed by the word `schema`. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, it works! I'm not using 3.x. Is this the only way to make it work in 2.x?

Comment: Yes. The compiler does not generate bytecode to look in outer scopes since you assign to it, so you must force it to be in the local scope instead.

Comment: I was looking for some similar implementations and I found this one: https://bitbucket.org/jpellerin/unittest2/src/3b0898db0e0f/unittest2/case.py This is very similar and it works. Please take a look at the skip decorator.

Comment: That decorator never assigns to `reason`.

Comment: If I try using the suggested method for Python 2, this forces the wrapped function to pass the "schema" argument - or it uses the wrapped function arguments to assign to "schema", so this doesn't really work for wrapping function with arguments